# generics collections.mixin raw and generic type. Integer -> String - exception but String -> Integer works good

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-conversion, type-erasure

I am confusing with two code snippets:

### snippet 1

```
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("1");
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
```

this code executes normally and outs `1` to console

### snippet 2

```
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(1);
    Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
```

Result of it - RuntimeException

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

I am confusing because both these rows are wrong:

```
    Integer integer = "123";
    String  string = 1;
```

It is compile error.

Why does for generis behaviour is different?

**P.S.**

I am prepare for scjp exam and don't mix raw type and  generics;

Comment: Type erasure. Your first example is a raw type.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Same with the second example.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Nothing's stopping it. Boxed Integers have toString just like any other object.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch I don't understand you

Comment: Try running `javap` on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PrintStream`, the class of `System.out`, has a number of `println` overloads. In particular, it has [an overload that takes an `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) and [an overload that takes a `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29).

In the first example,

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("1");
Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
System.out.println(iterator.next());
```

the compiler expects `iterator.next()` to produce an `Integer`, and the best match for that is the `Object` version of `println`. The compiler generates a call to the `Object` version of the method, which happens to work just fine for the `String` that actually comes out of the iterator.

In the second example,

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add(1);
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
System.out.println(iterator.next());
```

the compiler expects `iterator.next()` to produce a `String`, and the best match for that is the `String` version of `println`. The compiler generates a call to the `String` version of the method, and due to type erasure (which makes the runtime type of `iterator.next()` `Object`), it generates a runtime cast from `Object` to `String`. This cast fails for the `Integer` that actually comes out of the iterator, causing the exception you see.

Comment: it is really hard example. But explanation looks like right.

Comment: So the problem was in ``System.out.println()` instead of `iterator.next()`. Nice answer.